# D3.js Bar Chart Error

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to graph a bar chart using a simple dataset by using D3.js. I managed to get most done, but I have one problem left. The bars on the very right GO OVER the y-axis and will not show correctly.

This is the code:

[codepen](https://codepen.io/charlie090/pen/oygWxr)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var dataset;
  var data;
  var date;
  var temp1 = [];
  var temp2 = [];
  var url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FreeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";
  d3.json(url, function(json) {
    dataset = json.data;  

    for (var j = 0; j < dataset.length; j++) {
      temp1[j] = dataset[j][1]
    }  
    data = temp1;

    for (var j = 0; j < dataset.length; j++) {
      temp2[j] = dataset[j][0]
    }  
    date = temp2;

    minDate = new Date(date[0]);
    maxDate = new Date(date[date.length - 1]);   

  var svgWidth = 1000;
  var svgHeight = 450;
  var barWidth = (svgWidth/data.length);
  var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", svgWidth)
    .attr("height", svgHeight);

  var xScale = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain([minDate, maxDate])
      .range([0, svgWidth]);

  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([svgHeight, 0]);

  var x_axis = d3.axisBottom()
    .scale(xScale);

  var y_axis = d3.axisRight()
    .scale(yScale);

  var xAxisTranslate = svgHeight - 20;

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0 " + xAxisTranslate  +")")
    .call(x_axis);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, -20)")
    .call(y_axis);

  var barChart = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
         return yScale(d);
    })
    .attr("height", function(d) { 
        return svgHeight - yScale(d); 
    })
    .attr("width", barWidth)
    .attr("transform", function (d, i) {
        var translate = [barWidth * i, - 20]; 
        return "translate("+ translate +")";
    });
 });
});
```

How do I get the bar chart to draw values in my dataset correctly/fully?

Comment: I put two duplicate targets on the top: the first link explains the problem, while the second link offers a solution. However, the best solution is this: do **not** use bars with a time scale.